# Cannot download GloVe embeddings. Have they been moved or is downloads.cs.stanford.edu down temporarily?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, word-embedding

I am attempting to download glove.840B.300d.zip. I used the link at https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/ and also ran `wget https://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.840B.300d.zip`. The output from wget looks as follows:

```
--2022-06-23 15:50:30--  (try: 2)  https://downloads.cs.stanford.edu/nlp/data/glove.840B.300d.zip
Connecting to downloads.cs.stanford.edu (downloads.cs.stanford.edu)|171.64.64.22|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

Does anyone know if this is a temporary issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found that someone opened an issue for this: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/issues/206

Downloading from https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/ is not currently possible.

However, Huggingface has mirrors for all of the GloVe sets that can be downloaded. Links to these are provided by a comment made on the GitHub issue by joelsewhere on June 22nd.

Comment: This is because of a power outage at Stanford due to fires cutting a PG&E line in June 2022. Things should be back to normal in a week or so….